# sphinx search AssertionError error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sphinx

I am trying ro run sphinx search with python but getting error

I try this code

```
python3

import sphinxapi 

client = sphinxapi.SphinxClient()

client.SetServer('127.0.0.1',9312)

client.Query("english","language_index")
```

get an error

```
client.Query("english","language_index")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sphinxapi/__init__.py", line 579, in Query
    assert (len(self._reqs) == 0)
AssertionError
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466220/sphinx-search-in-python3-django